# How to fix 'Invalid input syntax for integer' issue while using sqlalchemy Declarative API

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm actually building a little utils which aims to take flat csv/excel file and populate a target database on MS Access - as I'm working on a Mac, i'm developping it using Postgres...

So I developped a part which deals with messy input (csv/excel) forms (several heading, etc) but that's not my issue at the moment.

On the other hand, I made my Database model using SQLAlchemy Declarative Base API.

I'm facing issue when importing data in some tables:
- Split flat record to several objects
- Check (SELECT) if the record doesn't exists yet based on uniqueness contraints
- If it doesn't exists I create object else I use the existing one
- Propagate keys information to related object

For some tables I'm using the auto_increment arguments but sometimes the record has its own ID (in input file) so I should it for insert/select in my tables and sometimes no ID so I have to create a new technical Id for my table.

Example: I have a record with for primary key -obsr25644- and sometimes nothing so I use a default value created with uuid.

So below the stacktrace when doing `select`operation on a my table. The same error occurs when working on existing data - obsr25644 - and generated uuid - 'a8098c1a-f86e-11da-bd1a-00112444be1e'

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) **invalid input syntax for integer**: "obsr25644"
LINE 3: WHERE "Location"."Id_observer" = 'obsr25644'
```

As you can see below, "Location"."Id_observer" is declared as String(255). I don't understand why the error is related to 'integer'.

```
[SQL: SELECT "Location"."Id_location" AS "Location_Id_location", [...], "Location"."Id_observer" AS "Location_Id_observer", 
FROM "Location" 
WHERE "Location"."Id_observer" = %(Id_observer_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
[parameters: {'Id_observer_1': 'obsr25644', 'param_1': 1}]
```

```
class LocationModel(UniqueMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Location'
    # Primary key
    Id_location = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    [...]
    Id_observer = Column(String(255), ForeignKey('Observer.Id_observer'))
    observer = relationship("ObserverModel", load_on_pending=True, back_populates="location")
```

```
class ObserverModel(UniqueMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Observer'
    # Primary key
    Id_observer = Column(String(255), primary_key=True, default=UniqueMixin.unique_hash())
    [...]
    # Relationship
    location = relationship("LocationModel", load_on_pending=True, back_populates="observer")
```

Note :UniqueMixin.unique_hash() returns uuid.uuid4().hex